# Error in compiling C code in NETBeans project

Tags: c, netbeans

I am currently facing problem in building my  C project in NETBeans. It shows me error as Access Denied when I compile my project.
Also it throws the same error while saving existing project or creating new project.

Current OS installed is Windows 7.

Following is the Error thrown :

```
arm-brcm-linux-gnueabi-g++: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)

Please submit a full bug report.

See <http://hi.baidu.com/__eabi> for instructions.

make[2]: *** [dist/V3/App/App.exe] Error 1

make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2

make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: The error message doesn't talk about _access denied_. It rather says you have found a bug and should report it. Did you do that? You did not provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem (no source code, no command line), so how should we help you?

Comment: Have you tried the general advice? 1. Reboot (in case some lingering process is locking files). 2. Check that you have write permission on all involved directories/files: (project files/source files/intermediate files/target files/Netbean configuration files)

Comment: @Klas : Yes , I have tried rebooting and have given full access to all the files. Yet there is a problem.

Comment: @Roland Illig : The Site mentioned <http://hi.baidu.com/__eabi is in different language. I don't know how to report the bug . Also I have compiled this code for the last one month and it was working fine. and just one day it started giving me this error.

Comment: The mentioned web site redirects to an error page, as you can see from the URL in the browser. So it seems to be unmaintained. To trace down the problem, you could install the Process Monitor from Sysinternals to see at which point collect2 crashes. Maybe this gives you a hint as to what changed in the last month.

Comment: Access denied could come from a virus scanner, and since they regularly update their definitions of what is a virus and what is not, this could also explain why it suddenly does not work anymore.

Comment: @Roland Illig : Thank you very much for the hint. I scanned my PC , but din't found any virus. But then I uninstalled my Anti-virus and to my surprise , the compilation was successful. Maybe the Anti-virus  was blocking some file.